# Most elegant way to wrap around integers

Tags: c, integer

This is a 16 bit unsigned value that the caller task assigns while sending a message. For each new message the value increments by one, eventually wrapping round and producing a sequence 0,1,2,……65533,65534,65535,0 etc. So I need a counter to find targets. I need help in getting the most efficient way to wrap around. For example if the current value is 65534 and my target count is 5, I need a function to wrap around and set the target to the correct value.

Comment: yes I did the method of checking for over flow and then subtracting the target from the wrap around and then modifying the new target value. Found it to be a long way to do a simple stuff!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an `unsigned int` counter then you can simply do `(x + 5) & 0xffffU` - there is no need to check for overflow because arithmetic in unsigned types is defined to wrap around in C, and unsigned types must use a pure binary representation.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer supports `uint16_t` (defined in `<stdint.h>` in C99 and C11 compilers), then use that.

```
uint16_t v = 65534;

v += 5;

assert(v == 3);
```

If your computer does not support `uint16_t`, then you can use:

```
unsigned int v = 65534;

v = (v + 5) & 0xFFFF;

assert(v == 3);
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19843181/2327831) says that is undefined behavior since `v` is promoted to `signed int` here `v += 5;`, and overflow on signed is undefined. Am I missing something? ( Maybe `v = ( unsigned int )v + 5u` would be correct? )

Comment: If a compiler broke this, I'd refuse to use the compiler.  There are two possibilities worth discussing, assuming CHAR_BIT is 8. Case (1): `sizeof(int) == 2`; then 65534 is an `unsigned int` and the behaviour is defined. Case (2): `sizeof(int)` is bigger than 2, so 65534+5 won't overflow, so the conversion back to `uint16_t` is safe.

Comment: Case(2):  `65534+INTMAX_MAX` will overflow. `+5` was never limited by anything so it might as well be max int.

Comment: It's meant to be 16-bit arithmetic; the increment should be limited to 65535.

Comment: Should be does not mean that it isn't UB and that it could not happen.

Comment: The code discusses primarily incrementing by one per message. If you're worried about large values of increment, you can mask that before adding.  It feels like you are quibbling about nothing. I don't plan to respond again.

Comment: That's ok, I didn't mean to antagonize you. I was just curious and i think details are important when it comes to such things.

Answer (score -2):

If it increments only by one, you can simply do the following:

```
#include <limits.h>

if (myint == (INT16_MAX - 1))
    counter++;
myint++;
```

However, the "correct" way to do it which will always detect overflow is as follows:

```
#include <limits.h>

if ((INT16_MAX - myint) < numtoadd)
    counter++;
myint += numtoadd;
```

Comment: INT16_MAX is 32767, not 65535.

Comment: This answer is a lot more complicated than it needs to be, since OP is working with unsigned values. caf's answer is better.