# Passing a negative to "%hu" in C

Tags: c, printf, codeblocks, unsigned, short

I can't get it to work in CodeBlocks
What will this code print? :

```
printf( "%hu" ,  ‐1 );
```

Comment: When you say that you "can't get it to work", what do you mean by that?

Comment: It's Undefined ... a possible outcome is that your program paints the ceiling yellow.

Comment: You can [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842215/wrap-around-explanation-for-signed-and-unsigned-variables-in-c).

Comment: Use online compilers...like ideone

Comment: @pmg it's not undefined, because the argument will be converted to `unsigned short` and that conversion is defined.

Comment: @iharob: thereis no conversion. `-1` has type `int`; `printf` is a function accepting a variable number of arguments. All values that fit the range of `int` get passed to `printf()` as `int`s. It worlks like this whether you included `<stdio.h>` (not including the header is another error)

Comment: @pmg I assume that inside `printf()` the argument gets converted according to the format specifier, which in some situations would cause undefined behavior. I haven't ever examined `printf()` implementation in detail to tell if I am right or not, so I just suppose it will be extracted from the variable arguments like `va_arg(args, unsigned int)`.

Comment: @iharob  `fprintf()` received an `int` (`-1`) yet was expecting an `unsigned` (`"%hu"`).  Thus "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined".  Many machines will take that `int -1` bit pattern and assume is is a bit pattern for `unsigned`, cast that pattern to `unsigned short` and merrily produce 65535, but it is still UB.

Comment: @Александар Стјепановић  Use `printf( "%hu" , (unsigned) ‐1 );`

Answer (score 7):

It will print `65535`

`"%hu"` is an `unsigned short int` which is 16 bit.

`-1` is "all-ones", e.g. `0xffff.ffff`, but since it gets converted to short it is only `0xffff`. Which is `65535` as unsigned.

Comment: Note: `unsigned short int` which is 16 bit is often true, but not defined by C.  C defines `unsigned short int` to be at _least_ 16 bit.  `-1 is "all-ones"` is also very often true (2's complement) but not defined by C to be so.

Comment: @chux - True. In principle we can't tell what the code would print without knowledge of the system being used. However, I'm confident that most systems out there uses 16 bits for shorts and 2's complement representation for signed integers.