# signed char overflow handling with GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, go, integer-overflow

The below example does not work as I expected (using ">" in the conditional) with GCC on an 8 bit machine, and neither on Linux 64 bit. If I make Timer_Secs and FutureTimeout_1Minute f.ex. 16 bits wide (int in those cases is 16 bits) it works as it should (using ">" in the conditional).

So, to get this to work for 8 bits with sign I seem to have to use "==" in the conditional.

```
{
    // Example with 8-bit only as tested with GCC 3.2 on AVR ATmega 128
    unsigned int  Cnt1 = 0; // 16 bits (kind of system clock)
    unsigned int  Cnt2 = 0; // 16 bits (observer, see what happens)
    signed   char Timer_Secs = 0; // 8 bits with sign
    signed   char FutureTimeout_1Minute = 60; // 8 bits with sign

    while (Cnt1 < 602) 
    { //                                         ## 
        if ((Timer_Secs - FutureTimeout_1Minute) == 0)
        {
            FutureTimeout_1Minute += 60; // Overflow/underflow allowed, 
                                         // so wraps and changes sign 
            Cnt2++; 
        } else {} // No code
        Timer_Secs++; 
        Cnt1++;
    } 
    //                 ## 
    // Cnt2 is 35 if >  0 above   #define AFTER_F(a,b)    ((a-b)>0)
    // Cnt2 is 35 if >= 0 above   #define AFTER_EQ_F(a,b) ((a-b)>=0)
    // Cnt2 is 10 if == 0 above   #define AFTER_ON_F(a,b) ((a-b)==0) **EXPECTED!**
}
```

The compare seems to involve some kind of sign conversion. I have not studied the assembly code for the different cases, since I thought this could be solved at code level.

- Why is this so?
- To me this looks plain wrong?
- Still I assume it's compiled like this by design?
- Is there some kind of type transfer or type decoration I could have done?

---

The context here is a blog note called "Know your timer's type" at: [blog]: http://www.teigfam.net/oyvind/home/technology/109-know-your-timers-type/

**Disclaimer**: this is a private blog with no money, ads, free things for me or etc. involved. Neither I nor anybody get anything from clicking on this url nor any of the urls in any of my blog notes.

**It works as expected in Go**, see blog note or http://play.golang.org/p/lH2SzZQEHG

It does not seem to work as expected in C++ either.

Comment: Related std-discussion mailing: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/topic/std-discussion/pdaoWRp8ZYg/discussion You can find many related questions on StackOverflow by searching for "signed integer overflow undefined behaviour". See also the [`-fwrapv` gcc option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options)

Comment: Very related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19842215/

Comment: Note that 8-bit operands to `+` are promoted to `int` which is at least 16 bits. @Øyvind, Please, if you don't mind, please describe what are the inputs and outputs of the snippet. "`Cnt2 is 35 if >  0 above`" doesn't make any sense so it's hard to tell what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't think the [tag:go] tag should have been added. Everything about this question is C/C++ related and although it might be worth noting in the question that other languages like Go have different behaviour I don't see anything here that would warrant putting this up for all followers/searchers of the Go tag.

Comment: (A)(B) Thanks for the refs to other discussions. I will study them. I actually did do some searches in advance

(A) -fwrapv did not help on the EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/LSL, for the 8 bit signed case (which is my case) 

(C) I thought it too long to supply three snippets, but please compile and run with '>', ">=" and "==" below "##", and print Cnt2.

(D) I agree not to bring in side cases, however the C/C++ and Go people won't hurt seeing how matters are solved by one other side. That's why I supplied a Go Playground code when I added the Go tag, so it could be verified