# Binary Search Middle Value Logic

Tags: algorithm, math, bit-manipulation, binary-search, integer-overflow

I've written binary search recursively with my own effort . While calculating middle index, I did `int mid = (low + high) / 2`. I googled recursive version of binary search and found that the calculation is a bug. Because it may overflow if `(low + high)` is greater than maximum value of integer. Two types solutions there are.

- `int mid = low + (high - low) / 2`
- `int mid = (high + low) >>> 1` (unsigned right shift, it does division by 2)

Both of them work like a charm. However, I wonder for first one how it works. Yes, it works but what the logic that the people think to find it is. For the second, how it works. Isn't there possibility to overflow for `(high + low)`  still? I mean my attempt is called as buggy because of overflow but the second one also does `(high + low)`.

Comment: shouldnt it be (high+low)>>>1 ?

Comment: @jackycflau Sorry, fixed, yes

Answer (score 3):

The reason the first one works is

- it is mathematically identical: `l + (h - l)/2 = l + h/2 - l/2 = l/2 + h/2 = (l + h)/2`, and
- because of the *precedence* of operations: first the parenthesis, then the division by 2, then the addition.

Funny enough though, this "solution" may still overflow on a large negative `low` so it is not really a solution to your original problem.

You could do something along the lines of `low/2 + high/2` to avoid overflow, but you will need to explicitly write out computations for even-even (the above), even-odd, odd-even and odd-odd to remain in the `int` space. While doing so you can utilize `>>>` to avoid the actual division.

Comment: Thank you. The identical really is helpful.

Comment: `low/2 + high/2` doesn't sound like a good workaround: consider the case where `low = 1` and `high = 3`: then `low / 2 + high / 2` would give `1` again (assuming integer division).

Comment: @MarkDickinson I understand that but was not clear enough expressing the thought. Now corrected, please validate

Answer (score 3):

In `(high + low) >>> 1`, there can still be signed wraparound, but the `>>>` operator treats its left operand as *unsigned* so signed wraparound is not relevant. This approach works because there won't be *unsigned* wraparound: `high` and `low` are (as signed integers) non-negative, so as unsigned integers they cannot be large enough to cause unsigned wraparound.

That adding two signed-non-negative integers never suffers from unsigned wraparound can be seen by adding the largest possible numbers: 2<sup>k-1</sup>-1 + 2<sup>k-1</sup>-1 (where k is the size in bits of the integer type, commonly 32), which adds up to 2<sup>k</sup>-2. That doesn't wrap yet: the highest representable number is 2<sup>k</sup>-1.

So it is not the "overflow" in `high + low` that really causes the problem, at least in a reasonable language where signed arithmetic is safe, such as Java. It is the subsequent treatment of the result of `high + low` as a signed integer by a hypothetical `/ 2` that follows it that causes trouble.

Comment: I hadn't known _wraparound_ is synonym of _overflow_ before your answer. Thanks for your answer. **However, why cannot unsigned integers be large enough to cause  unsigned wraparound?** Could you exemplify it?

Comment: @snr they're not *exact* synonyms, for example in C signed addition can overflow, but only *maybe* wraps, it can also cause various sorts of breakage.

Comment: maybe wraps? **Signed integer variables do not have wrap-around behavior in C language.** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842215/wrap-around-explanation-for-signed-and-unsigned-variables-in-c

Comment: @snr that just means there is no guarantee, not that it definitely doesn't happen

Comment: Yes right, **why cannot unsigned integers be large enough to cause unsigned wraparound? Could you exemplify it?**

Comment: I'm a tad bewildered. Thanks. En passant about wraparound I gotcha from [here](http://qr.ae/TUTMUT).

Answer (score 1):

Assume your integers are 16-bit signed (just for brevity; scale them up if you need 32-bit integers).

The range is -32768...32767.

An example where `low + (high - low) / 2` will overflow:

```
low = -20000
high = 30000
high - low = 50000 = (after overflow) -15536
(high - low) / 2 = -7768
low - (high - low) / 2 = -27768
```

An example where `(high + low) >>> 1` will overflow:

```
low = -20000
high = -10000
low + high = -30000 = (binary) 1000101011010000
(low + high) >>> 1 = (binary) 0100010101101000 = 17768
```

Calculating average without any possibility for overflow is inefficient, and can be performed in multiple ways:

1. Convert to higher "precision" first, e.g. 32-bit to 64-bit; convert back after calculating the average
2. Divide your numbers by 2 and use some sort of "remainder"

   ```
   low2 = low >>> 1;
   high2 = high >>> 1;
   low_remainder = low & 1; // get the lowest significant bit
   high_remainder = high & 1; // get the lowest significant bit
   avg2 = low2 + high2; // this cannot overflow
   avg = avg2 + (low_remainder + high_remainder) / 2; // this cannot overflow
   ```

   I am not sure this exact code works; it's just an idea.
3. Calculate the average the usual way, then check for "unexpected" result (the average is smaller than `low` or greater than `high`). If unusual, calculate it the "safe" way.
4. Somehow make sure your input cannot cause overflow. This doesn't work for libraries, but often works in real applications, where you have an upper bound like 10000 on all your numbers. Or **maybe your numbers are nonnegative; then `low + (high - low) / 2` actually cannot overflow**.

Comment: Thank you for another perspective. _maybe your numbers are nonnegative; then low + (high - low) / 2 actually cannot overflow._ yes it's right because array indexes commence from 0.