# Loop Structure that Increments variable until it overflows?

Tags: c, macos

This problem for my intro to C coding class states:

> Write  a program that  will  determine  the  biggest  positive  value that  your  machine  can  achieve  for  each  of  the  following  data  types.  (and  thus  you  can  figure  out  the number of bits used for each of the data types).  In order to find the biggest value, use a simple loop structure that increments a variable of that datatype, until it overflows.

It instructs me to do it with multiple data types, such as `int`, `char`, `short int`, etc.

Im not really sure what the question is asking, am I just supposed to make an infinite loop that takes a variable of certain data type, and increase its value every time until it gets so big that the program breaks?? Or is it asking something totally different

Comment: If a variable overflows, the program won't break by itself; If the variable is `signed`, [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) will occur and if it's `unsigned`, it will [wraparound](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19843181/9200752).

Comment: You need do create a loop that increment a variable, until it became lesser that it was, see my answer to why this happens

Answer (score 1):

Overflow happens when the data is too big to fit in the data type, what it happens is that the value overflows and precision is lost.

Let's suppose that we're working with two bits, so we have this table

```
00
01
10
11
```

These are all the numbers values that fit, in two bits. `11` in binary is 3 in decimal, if you increment it you will get `100`, if you truncate this to less significant bits you have, `00` which is 0, and this is the behavior that you're searching.

I will let the implementation as an exercise for you, since this is homework

Answer (score 0):

cheat sheet for the final numerical answers `#include <limits.h>`

it took much longer than i expect in my practice, and assigning the value of 2^(N) - 10  causes compiler warning.

where N is the number of available bits to store numerical parts of the variable, and by the example from @geckos , by a total bit of 2,  1 for the negative/positive sign, 1 for storing the numerical part, the max signed value would be 1 = (2^1 -1)

so i took the limits.h advantage to shorten the loop times to reach a overflow

finish the actual implementation by yourself though.